# how to get the value of time left for a transient

Tags: php, transient

I am setting up a transient with one hour expiry time.
Now i want to know how much time left for the transient to expire.

I am getting the transient timeout value with get_option function.

Can anyone help me out.

Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that if the site is actually using something like Redis, or any other supported "external cache" then nothing is going to actually be set in the options table (which can be checked with `wp_using_ext_object_cache`)

Storage in the options table is just how WordPress handles transients outside of any external caching (or local object caching).

With that said, to calculate the time remaining, you would do something like this:

```
$expires = (int) get_option( '_transient_timeout_MY_TRANSIENT_NAME', 0 );
$time_left = $expires - time();
```

The value for expiration is calculated by adding `time()` to the value passed when setting the transient, so to get time left, just subtract `time()` from the value set for expiration

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in WordPress function to get the transient timeout. But you can use the following function to get the transient timeout.

```
function get_transient_timeout( $transient ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $transient_timeout = $wpdb->get_col( "
      SELECT option_value
      FROM $wpdb->options
      WHERE option_name
      LIKE '%_transient_timeout_$transient%'
    " );
    return $transient_timeout[0];
}
```

Comment: Just realized that you asked for the time left. This function will return the expiration time. To get the time left, subtract the current time.

Comment: Hi @Nathan thanks for the reply. We can the same by get_option() function in wordpress.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question then. The value of the transient timeout is a UNIX time stamp, so to get the time left, just subtract time().

Comment: The WordPress `set_transient()` function does use the PHP `time()` function for the current time value. If you want to calculate the time remaining for transients using SQL, you can use a query like `SELECT o.*, option_value - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS seconds_remaining, FROM_UNIXTIME(option_value) as utc_expiration FROM wp_options o WHERE o.option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout_%' ORDER BY o.option_id desc LIMIT 100;`

Comment: should `return ($transient_timeout) ? $transient_timeout[0] : false;`

Answer (score 0):

Transients by definition can expire at any moment, no matter what interval you have requested, therefor the "time till expiry" can not be reliably determined. you can hack something by inspecting the "raw" option, but it is a bad idea to relay on it.